# assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] when training logistic regression model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series

I'm trying to build a simple logistic regression model for time-series prediction. However, when I try to train the model I get the following error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (loss/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [64 1] [y (loss/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [64 45]
     [[node loss/output_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal_1/Assert/Assert (defined at C:/Users/jani/PycharmProjects/RNN_trade/base.py:156) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_2798]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

Batch size is 64, and I'm trying to pass 45 timestep sequences to the model. The model consists of one layer. In code:

```
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(Dense(2, activation="softmax"))
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, decay=1e-6)
model2.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              optimizer=opt,
              metrics=["accuracy"])
```

I've tried to change all of the parameters for the model (optimizer, loss etc) but nothing seems to work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please can you share complete code to replicate your issue, so that it's easy to provide solution.